# How can I use date time and days in my laravel migration?

Tags: php, laravel

I know how to use date and dateTime. But in this case I want my data to be like 2023-03-03 Friday. Does laravel provides something like this?

this is my code

```
$table->date('estimate_time_arrival');
```

how can i modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to store the date in default format(Y-m-d). use the Laravel casts feature.

Method 1 : [Defining An Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

```
 protected function estimateTimeArrival(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn (string $value) => Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d l'),
        );
    }
```

and if you print `$record->estimate_time_arrival` and `$record->toArray()` will output like below

[image]

Method 2 : [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in your model

```
 protected $casts=[
        'estimate_time_arrival' => 'datetime:Y-m-d l',
    ];
```

and if you print `$record->estimate_time_arrival` and `$record->toArray()` will output like below

[image]

if you see output then if we try to access directly then it return carbon object and formatted output only return if you use `toArray()`

Method 3 :

```
 protected $casts=[
        'estimate_time_arrival' => 'datetime:Y-m-d l',
    ];
```

and if you print `$record->estimate_time_arrival->format('Y-m-d l')` and `$record->toArray()` will output like below

[image]

Comment: This was so helpful. sorry I can't vote this answer due to my reputation

Answer (score 3):

You can store values as dateTime in the database and then use model casts like this:

```php
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        ...
        'estimate_time_arrival' => 'datetime:Y-m-d l',
    ];
}
```

You can read more about date casting and other types of casting [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)

Answer (score 1):

You define an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on your model to create a custom formatted date attribute:

```
public function getFormattedEstimateTimeAttribute()  
{
  return $this->estimate_time_arrival->format('Y-m-d l');
}
```

Then access it like:

```
$model->formatted_estimate_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timestamp or datetime column type in your migration to store the date and time information.

```
$table->timestamp('estimate_time_arrival');
```

THen for diplay you can do something like...

```
$record = DB::table('your_table_name')->first();

$timestamp = Carbon::parse($record->estimate_time_arrival);
$formattedDateTime = $timestamp->format('Y-m-d l'); // Produces "2023-03-03 Friday"
```